# Where's ATLAS installed on Ubuntu 18.04 Mate on ARM CPU?

Tags: 18.04, mate, arm

I installed Atlas on Ubuntu 18.04 Mate using the command

```
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
```

I'm running this on an Odroid N2 (https://www.hardkernel.com/shop/odroid-n2-with-4gbyte-ram/), so it's an ARM system.

While the command to install it works, I can't find where it gets installed.  I am trying to run GAMESS (https://www.msg.chem.iastate.edu/gamess/) and part of the configuration asks where I have installed ATLAS.  In Ubuntu 16.04 Mate on an Odroid XU4, it was installed to /usr/lib/atlas-base, but I can't find it there.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Ask the packaging system: `dpkg -L libatlas-base-dev`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consult with output of APT on the local system

```
dpkg -L libatlas-base-dev
```

or use search on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libatlas-base-dev/filelist).

But better way is to use `pkg-config` as `libatlas-base-dev` have two related files:

1. `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/blas-atlas.pc`
2. `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/lapack-atlas.pc`

So you can use `pkg-config --libs --cflags lapack-atlas blas-atlas` to get libraries names and include-paths.

Comment: Awesome answers, N0rbert and waltinator.  Thanks!